# jWebSocket + Apple APNS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use jWebSocket to send Push Notifications from a web form to the Apple APNS servers. I can't seem to figure it out, and there doesn't seem to be any information on how to go about this elsewhere. I am using an XQuery written web application so they don't seem to have a build in capability for sockets, hence jWebSocket.

Can anyone suggest a tutorial or provide information on whether this is possible?